# How to populate custom list View under fragment activity (extends Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I want to Add Simple List View of some items under `Fragment` activity which is extending `Fragment` but not `ListFragment`.

Here is My code :

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {

String[] ibizzproducts=
        {
                "Attendance",
                "GPS",
                "CCTV"
                "Website"
                "Application"

        };

ListView listView;


public static ProductListFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    ProductListFragment fragment = new ProductListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ProductListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

     for(int i=0;i < ibizzproducts.length;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", "Products Here : " + ibizzproducts[i]);

    aList.add(hm);
   }

   String[] from = { "Products Here" };

int[] to = { R.id.listView1};

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container, false);

 // ListView list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_product_list, from, to);

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
```

If I am using this in `onCreateView()`, thn its giving me error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter
```

I just want to add simple `ListView` , so that if i select `Product` from the navigation Drawer, it should show me this simple List of product items.

please , help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: `ibizzproducts ` Array contains only 3 items but `for-loop` execution until `i==9` that's why getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException `

Comment: oh ,its my mistake , i correct it. But now it gives me null pointer exception and pointing on this line    " listView.setAdapter(adapter);  "

Comment: Never use local variables for size in loops if you are iterating any array.

Comment: Post your adapter class

Comment: @GauravSetia: this is another issue see my and other answers which will tell u why getting NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code from  `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` to  `list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Keep your eyes open while copy-paste is being done

Comment: Now, its giving me error : " IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter" ... @jas

Comment: You cannot pass multiple parameters through SimpleAdapter. For that, you have to create Custom adapter class.

Comment: Refer http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: Yes , problem is with the simpleAdapter. Let me Just Create Custom one .  @jas

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`listView` object is `null` because `getActivity().findViewById` is used to access ListView from `fragment_product_list` layout which is layout of Fragment.

Because `list` object of ListView is initialized from `fragment_product_list` which is returned from `onCreateView` method so used it  to `setAdapter` for `ListView`:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I just Edit my Error , please Go through once more who answered this.

Comment: @GauravSetia: Remove `listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);`  line and Change `ListView list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);` to `listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

Comment: I change as u suggest : Now, its giving me error : " IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter" ... @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @GauravSetia: not possible please share latest code and error

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K :please check in Comment , i  have shared my code and some part of Log

Comment: @GauravSetia: Remove `getActivity().getBaseContext()` this and use `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

It is better:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ibizzproducts.length; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", "Products Here : " + ibizzproducts[i]);
    aList.add(hm);
}
```

Comment: Now, its giving me error : " IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter" ... @walkman

Answer (score 1):

i hope it will help you

public class FragmentShowAll extends Fragment {

```
ListView listViewMsg;
ArrayList<String> array_list=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_all, container, false);

       array_list.add("hello");
       array_list.add("hello");
       array_list.add("hello");
       array_list.add("hello");
       array_list.add("hello");

    listViewMsg = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewMsg);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
    listViewMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//on click action
        }
    });//listview on click

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: what is listViewUser Here :

Comment: Thanks, replace listViewMsg with listViewUser.... rest works fine , I appreciate :) Thanks